# Javascript globalAlpha completely fading screen to black

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm using this javascript code to slowly fade anything on the canvas (`ctx`) to black:

```
function screenFill() {
  ctx.globalAlpha = 0.01;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(-10, -10, window.innerWidth + 20, window.innerHeight + 20);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
}
```

The only problem is that the colors on the screen never reach black, but end up as an ugly gray.

Is there any way I could fix that?

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e36dpaax/) showing my work.

Comment: You can not fade completely to black because of rounding errors on the canvas. You can decrease the residue by using globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out" in the screenFill function which will fade to transparent rather than a color and then set the canvas background color to what you want it to fade to and by setting the global alpha to a higher value and just skip every 2nd 3rd or how ever many frames to get the same fade rate

Comment: Thank you! That really helps